# ErrorQuotaExceeded when sending from Shared Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've got a web app which uses Microsoft Graph API To send emails from a shared mailbox but is currently having some problems.

I use the following permissions `['user.read', 'mail.readwrite', 'mail.readwrite.shared', 'mail.send', 'mail.send.shared']` that are granted by the user on logging and the shared mail box is called with the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[shared-mail]` url.

Before yesterday the emails were being sent, I can see the emails on the shared mailbox inbox (`/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$top=50`) and move them to different folders (`messages/[id]/move`).

My users can still send from their outlook apps emails as the shared mailbox without problems.

When using the Microsoft Graph Explorer or my web app, the error is also showing which leads me to think it's only happening when calling the MSGraph API.

When I call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[sharedMail]/sendMail`, I get a `403 - Forbidden` back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorQuotaExceeded",
    "message": "Cannot submit message."
  }
}
```

Some guesses I've got are:

- There exists some kind of limit when sending email from Microsoft Graph API that I have reached (which is unlikely because there is usually only 40 emails per day).
- I need another permission scope to be able to send using the explorer and shared mailboxes.

Does anyone know if there is any problem with my configuration or the way I'm handling shared mailboxes send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error implies that the mailbox has exceeded its storage quota. The quota gets configured in Exchange. See [Configure storage quotas for a mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/storage-quotas?view=exchserver-2019) for details on how to set/change a mailbox's quota.

Comment: Oh thank you for the fast answer, it seems the mailbox is over 100% of its capacity. I will ask my users to clean some space and try again. If it works I will mark as solved :D!

Comment: Was this successful?

Comment: Yeah, today they finished the backup and cleaning of the email and it worked again. Thank you!

Comment: The API response and this answer is a rather convoluted way to say **YOUR MAILBOX IS FULL, Delete some stuff!**